# Avoiding Jerk during trajectory preemption in MoveIt!

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have noted that the robot is jerking a bit during cancelling the existing trajectory goal. What can be the reason?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307121/avoiding-jerk-during-trajectory-preemption-in-moveit!/) by [Lentin Joseph](https://answers.ros.org/users/22117/lentin-joseph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the solution. There is a parameter  called "**stop_trajectory_duration**" in trajectory controller. Just adjust this value to make the ending smooth.

http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller

---

Originally posted by [Lentin Joseph](https://answers.ros.org/users/22117/lentin-joseph/) with karma: 66 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1